# Semicolon or period in the following?

Tags: semicolons, periods

Here are two instances in a formal paper I submitted where my professor told me my semicolon  usage is incorrect.  He says that, in both instances, a period should be used.  Is he right?  I maintain that I've used them appropriately and at my discretion to indicate closeness of subject matter between two independent clauses.

Instance 1:

> Baz Luhrmann, in his 2013 film adaptation of Fitzgerald’s work by the same name, represents its major characters in a manner mostly true to the novel; Nick, Gatsby, Daisy and Tom are somewhat polarized, however, in their speech and actions.

Instance 2:

> In the novel, when Nick is “urged” (28) by Myrtle to go along, bribed with the promise of Myrtle’s sister, he responds “Well, I’d like to, but—” (28); in the film, he worriedly says, “No, no, no—that’s alright.”

Comment: You're missing your sentences.

Comment: I'd ***love*** to know what (if anything) was going through the mind of whoever upvoted this "question". But like OP, I'm not either.

Comment: Sorry. I hit enter and it was posted prematurely...

Comment: @Fumble - Only a guess, but it might have been Nick's comment that prompted the upvote. To the OP: The semi-colon in Instance 2 seems okay to me, but I'd have to side with your professor for Instance 1.

Comment: This would be considered by some as off-topic because it's about writing and not *really* about English Language. Also, it's about critique rather than grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that, yes, your usage is correct.

For more information, I refer to the ever humorous Oatmeal:  http://theoatmeal.com/comics/semicolon

(And for the serious readers, I refer to this excellent answer about however: [Use of a semicolon before and comma after "however"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104864/use-of-a-semicolon-before-and-comma-after-however))

As an aside, I think putting *however* at the beginning of the second independent clause in the first sentence would make it stronger.  Something like:

> Baz Luhrmann, in his 2013 film adaptation of Fitzgerald’s work by the same name, represents its major characters in a manner mostly true to the novel; *however*, Nick, Gatsby, Daisy and Tom are somewhat polarized in their speech and actions.