# Punctuations in front of “however”

Tags: punctuation

Very long ago, when I was young, my teacher once told me that there only should a **period** “.” or a **semicolon** ”;” in front of “***however***”, but never a ***comma*** “,”.

To be specific,

> **“xxx**. ***However***, **xxx”**

and

> **”xxx**; ***however***, **xxx”**

is right; whereas,

> **”xxx**, ***however***, **xxx”**

is wrong.

However, I rarely see such rules in people’s writings even those very formal ones.

The teacher was really knowledgeable that he wouldn’t have said that if that made no sense.

I’m now confused, and I’d appreciate it if any help is given.

Comment: Please provide an example of formal writing where "however" is flanked by two commas. And, by the way, teachers are human they can forget about exceptions, or choose to talk about them at a later date. I wouldn't worry so much, the correct usage of commas and semi-colons are not that big a deal in everyday life. They're only essential for formal essays, papers, and in novels. In speech, never.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*However* is more complicated than that.

Your teacher's rule holds when *however* has the contrastive sense, approximately "in spite of that", AND it introduces a new independent clause.

But it does not hold when *however* falls later in a clause it modifies, OR when *however* introduces a fused relative clause and has the sense *in whatever manner*, OR *however* acts as an adverb of degree; in these cases it may (but not must) be comma-bracketed:

> Bill failed. John, however, succeeded.
>   Bill failed. John succeeded, however.
>   Bill failed, however he approached the problem.
>   Bill failed, however hard he tried.

Comment: I would say the comma is optional in the last sentence. "Bill failed however hard he tried" makes perfect sense as well.

Comment: @sgroves What I said is that *all* the comma-bracketings in those sentences are optional--I  use commas to indicate how I want the line to be spoken/heard.

Comment: @StoneyB Same, and whoops, I missed where you said that!

Comment: I had forgotten the distinction between adverb of degree *however* and the relative pro-form *however*; excellent answer! There's another (informal?) usage of *however*, as an emphatic form of *how*, as in "However did you manage that?" (I read that recently in [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/104877) great answer here.)